# Vuejs : use imported plugin mixin localy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

Is it possible to use a mixin imported from a VueJS plugin in one component?

I've created a plugin and when I import it I can access the mixin's functions from all my components.

Is there a way to make it available in only one component ? or all the plugin add global-level functionality to Vue by definition?

Comment: Simply put: Sure, it is. Just register that mixin within a specific component and you're good to go.

Comment: Didn't work, even if I register it in one component it became available to all the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a mixin either globally, either locally. If you don't register a mixin globally, it will be only available in components where it is locally registered. **So, with local registration, you can make a mixin available in only specific components**.

**Registering globally:** you just need to declare it in the `main.js` file

*Nb: you don't need to register the mixin in components*

- Vue 2:

```js
// main.js
import myMixin from './mixins/myMixin'

Vue.mixin(myMixin)     // makes the plugin globally available 
new Vue({
   // ...
}).$mount('#app')
```

- Vue 3:

```js
// main.js
import myMixin from './mixins/myMixin'

const app = createApp(App)
app.mixin(myMixin)     // makes the plugin globally available 
app.mount('#app')
```

**Registering locally**: you do NOT declare it in the `main.js` file, and you register the mixin in the relevant components

```js
// componentWithMixin.vue
import myMixins from "../mixins/myMixin"

export default {
    // ...
    mixins: [myMixins]     // importing the mixin - without this line, the mixin can't be available
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should use create 2 things:

- the plugin that imports the essentials globally
- the mixin that needs to be imported in the components you want

example:

```
//main.js
import {MyPlugin} from 'my-library'

vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

in the component

```
//component.vue
import {MyMixin} from 'my-library'

export default {
   mixins: [myMixin],
}
```